# Asynchronously sort GridView in ASP.NET MVC using Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, gridview, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using [WebGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx) to display data on client side, `canSort: true` is set.

The [view](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/asp-net-mvc-views-overview-cs) code is:

```
@model UI.Models.TestModel

@if (Model.listTestModel != null)
{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model.listTestModel,
    null,
    defaultSort: "ColumnA",
    rowsPerPage: 25,
    canPage: true,
    canSort: true
    );

    @grid.GetHtml(
     mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,

    columns: grid.Columns
            (
            grid.Column(columnName: "ColumnA", header: "ColumnA"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "ColumnB", header: "ColumnB")
            )
            )

}
```

I'm able to sort data by clicking column headers.

**Problem:**

How can someone asynchronously sort the WebGrid using Ajax?

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518039/asp-net-mvc-3-webgrid-sorting-remains-sortdir-asc

Comment: Hi @Dean.DePue - The suggestion is nice because the `ModelState` is the problem for me as well, however *in this particular case* I'm concerned more with asynchronous loading

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but isn't the answer to this in the MSDN magazine link you have used in your question? Under the heading `AJAX: Client-Side Changes`?

Comment: @JamieDunstan - I think you're right. I only saw the upper half. +2 for opening my eyes!

Comment: @student - you are welcome. If you get working, maybe you can write an answer here for future visitors so that they can quickly see the solution :)

Comment: @JamieDunstan - Sure bro! I will surely do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [Jamie Dunstan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003053/sort-gridview-in-asp-net-mvc-using-ajax?noredirect=1#comment55762891_34003053) for pointing this out.

> One need to make sure that the entire `WebGrid` code is inside a div with a **unique id**. Also, jQuery is referenced while Javascript is enabled.

```
 <div id='unique id goes here'>

@model UI.Models.TestModel

@if (Model.listTestModel != null)
{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model.listTestModel,
    null,
    defaultSort: "ColumnA",
    rowsPerPage: 25,
    canPage: true,
    canSort: true,
    ajaxUpdateContainerId: "unique id goes here"
    );

    @grid.GetHtml(
     mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,

    columns: grid.Columns
            (
            grid.Column(columnName: "ColumnA", header: "ColumnA"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "ColumnB", header: "ColumnB")
            )
            )

}
<div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

  function updateGrid(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var grid = $(this).parents('.ajaxGrid');
    var id = grid.attr('id');
    grid.load(url + ' #' + id);
  };
  $('.ajaxGrid table thead tr a').on('click', updateGrid);
  $('.ajaxGrid table tfoot tr a').on('click', updateGrid);
 });
</script>
```

Notice that `.live` function is [replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34022700/revisions) with `.on` because of [depreciation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19110917/2404470)

Comment: Yeah, finally it works like a charm. Thanks for pointing that out :)